# Bluemix Cloud Auto Scaling Service Crashed our Running Watson App now

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, autoscaling, continuous-delivery

Our Watson app based on Dialogue Service was running this morning, and this app has many users. Then I saw your 2017 DevOps tutorials video on Youtube on using Auto Scaling Service to scale web apps on Bluemix.  Then I connected our this Watson app with the Auto Scaling app.  Then, right way, this watson app is crashed. So, I tried to unbind this Auto Scaling App from this Watson app, but it cannot be done.  So, I had to delete this Auto Scaling Service from this Watson app.

After that, this Watson app cannot be started.  Hope that Bluemix cloud team and Auto Scaling Service team reply here soon.  If anybody also have got such horrible experiences with the Bluemix cloud Auto Scaling Service, I also like to hear some input from you. Thank you !

Comment: If anybody also have got such horrible experiences with the Bluemix cloud Auto Scaling Service, I also like to hear some input from you. Thank you !

Comment: Who voted down this Q?  Shame on you !  If you have problem with this Q, you should dare to post your comments and solve this problem here for us.  if this is done by the staff from Bluemix, it is a shame !  This will only make Bluemix and Auto Scaling Service look even worse.  Bluemix advised its customers to post Q here and they will reply here.

Comment: The IBM Bluemix team has a policy never to vote down reasonable questions about their technologies. Your question sounds as though you have a very specific troubleshooting problem with how the Watson and Autoscaling services interacted on your system. Your best bet is to open a Support ticket by clicking Support in the top right of your Bluemix console and selecting "Add ticket." You can also get good answers about Bluemix on https://developer.ibm.com/answers/smartspace/bluemix/

Comment: I'm editing your tags to ensure the right IBM SMEs see your question.

Comment: Can you please post your logs? `cf logs APPLICATION_NAME --recent`

Comment: Hi Ralphearle, Finally, somebody from Bluemix team replied.  We have opened the support ticket at the same time with this Q, but we have not heard anything from our ticket to Bluemix. Bluemix always reminds its users that we will receive reply faster if we post our Q here.

Comment: ralphearle, thanks. The support Ticket #5377-13180322 is opened with all the app running logs at the same time with this Q. But no reply has not been received yet.

Answer (score 1):

In the past week I have seen similar issues, and the culprit might be the auto-scaling service.  The culprit might also be the new Diego deployment (as opposed to the old DEA droplets).  Take a look at the Diego documentation.  I have not had the time yet to fully debug this, but I went out and diabled Diego for my app and then attempted to redeploy.  This allowed me to bring my app up successfully - now I still need to figure out WHY it has problems, since we will be forced to migrate to Diego at some point.

Comment: Hi Daniel, Great info. I agree with you that  "auto-scaling service"  caused this problem.  I am not happy with this: Bluemix Cloud did not give warning about this problem of  "auto-scaling service" before letting its users add this service to their working app, the experienced team should have done this.  By the way, is your app based on Watson Dialogue Service/API?  Thanks

Comment: Nope - I have a simple app using Node and a MongoDB.

Comment: Tried to migrate to Diego again today and it worked.  My Node app running with a MongoDB backend is running fine with Diego.  You might want to give it another shot.

Comment: Thank you ! The cause of this problem is found: The Dialog_ID is deleted from the front end code by the Auto Scaling Service.  This app is still on DEA platform.

Comment: IBM Bluemix support staff Jeff found the above key cause of this crash.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that the problem is not with the AutoScaling service. Cloud Foundry in Bluemix recently upgraded to the Diego architecture. Your application might need some changes to work with Diego. Binding any service to an applciation will trigger a restage which might have caused this update.

Currently, you can disable diego to see if this resolves your application crash.

```
$ cf disable-diego APPLICATION_NAME

$ cf start APPLICATION_NAME
```

Try this.

Then deploy your app under a new name and gather the logs `cf logs APPLICATION_NAME --recent`

https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/manageapps/depapps.html?cm_mc_uid=70239858576514840828532&cm_mc_sid_50200000=#appdeploy

Comment: Thanks for the input. Our app is still on DEA now. It was working right before adding AutoScaling service.

Comment: Keep in mind that you will need to install the Diego enabler plugin - https://github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/Diego-Enabler